# Ampleness, Nakai's criterion and pullback

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

In the book I'm reading ( [Geometry of Algebraic Curves](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-0-387-90997-4) ), at some point (page $310$) they make the following claim:

> One can use Nakai's criterion to establish the general fact that if $f:X\to Y$ is any finite surjective map and $L$ is a line bundle over $Y$, then $f^*L$ is ample if and only if $L$ is ample.

Do you know about any reference where I can find a proof for this statement?

Or could you give the sketch of a proof here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference: Lazarsfeld, *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry* Volume 1, Proposition 1.2.13 and Corollary 1.2.28. I'll reproduce the arguments here for completeness.

To see that the finite pullback of an ample line bunde $L$ is still ample, use Serre's criterion: the projection formula shows that for any coherent sheaf $F$ on $Y$, the higher cohomology groups $H^i(Y, F \otimes f^*L^m)$ vanish for sufficiently large $m$, so Serre says that $f^*L$ is ample.

To show that if $f^*L$ is ample then $L$ must be, take an irreducible subvariety $V \subset Y$. We want to show that $L^{\operatorname{dim} \ V} \cdot V >0$. Take an irreducbile subvariety $W \subset X$ mapping finitely to $Y$: then it's not too hard to see that

$$ (f^*L)^{\operatorname{dim} \ V} \cdot W = \operatorname{deg}(W \rightarrow V) \left( L^{\operatorname{dim} \ V} \cdot V \right). $$

Now Nakai tells us that the left-hand side is strictly positive, therefore so too is the right, as required.